# Regarding Assembly Language Loops

Tags: loops, assembly, x86

Can anyone explain what this code does? I kind of understand it, but I don't quite understand what happens when the code label appears below "loop N-Not-1". I'm not sure if I understand loops correctly. I think of them as `do-while` loops in C++. In this case, wouldn't the loop for N-is-1 continue indefinitely? I thought this was a if-else statement and not a loop?

> Write a piece of code that computes the function below:
>   if (N = 1) then Y = -X
>   else
>   Y=X
>   Assume that the value of X is in the eax register. Also assume that the value of N is in the
>   ebx register. The computed value of Y need to be placed in the eax register.
>   Hint 1: Use a loop instruction in your code.
>   Hint 2: This problem can be solved using less than five instructions.
>
> ```
>    ; eax = X, ebx = N
>     ; Write your code below
>     mov ecx, ebx
>     loop N-not-1 
>     N-is-1: neg eax
>     N-not-1: ; Y = eax
> ```

Answer (score 1):

`loop` instruction operates on the value of ECX. It decreases ECX first and checks whether it is zero. If it is not zero, then it jumps to the specified address. If it is zero then break.

```
mov ecx, ebx    ; this instruction moves the value of N to ecx
loop N-not-1    ; if N is 1 then, on decrementing it becomes 0 and the loop breaks. 

N-is-1: neg eax ; if N is 1, eax gets negated as the loop breaks
N-not-1:        ; Y = eax // if N is not 1, eax remains unchanged
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this code is very badly presented.  I am copying it here without the clutter:

```
    mov ecx, ebx
    loop N-not-1 
    neg eax
N-not-1:
```

This code is a hack.  It does not actually loop.  It just makes use of the fact that the loop instruction will do 3 things : decrement ecx, check if it is zero, and jump all in one instruction.  It is equivalent to the following:

```
    dec ebx
    cmp ebx, 0
    jnz N-not-1 
    neg eax
N-not-1:
```

Answer (score -1):

`loop` instruction is like the following C code:

```c
for (; ecx != 0; ecx--) {
     // instructions
}
```

and your code use loop instruction for checking ebx(N) against zero:

```c
ebx = N;
ecx = ebx;
for (; ecx != 0; ecx--) {
     // if ecx=1 (N = 1) we enter the loop
     eax = -eax
}
Y = eax
```

I used C like code, but in assembly there is no block and everything is controlled with labels.